# Get mongo shell BinData as string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, utf-8, decode, mongo-shell

How do I convert BinData object that contains UTF-8 encoded text to a string?

I'm using [MongoDB shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) (the `mongo` command). It's basically Javascript interactive console (I think it's SpiderMonkey), but there is no `Buffer` object like in Node.js to work with the hex or base64 format that BinData object provides.

Answer (score 1):

I can use conversion from BinData to hex and then parse the hex string.

```
function hex2a(hexStr) {
  var s = ''; 
  for (let i=0; i<hexStr.length; i+=2) 
    s += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexStr.substr(i, 2), 16));
  return s;
}

hex2a(BinData(0,"aGVsbG8=").hex())
// returns "hello"
```

But that works correctly only with ASCII.